# Mongoose/MongoDB : How to update item which is nested 4 levels down?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my mongo database I have a tree like this:

```
-shopping-lists
  |- list
       |-products
           |-item
           |-item
 |- list
           |-products
               |-item
               |-item
```

I need to find which shopping list I'm updating and then go to products array, find an item inside and update one property. 
I'm trying to solve this from few hours right now, but didn't find any solution. [image]

How to update item which is nested 4 levels down??

Comment: Do you need to do this in one query or you can use multiple queries?

Comment: @bhalu007 It's not specified how many queries. Would be perfect to achieve final solution

Comment: Could you show actual documents instead of screen shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 6 hours of investigation, I have found an answer. 
For any of you guys, having the same problem here is the answer.

While adding a new item to the Parent model, I've been just pushing these items as plain objects and the Parent model was like this:

```
const Parent = new Schema(
  {
    description: { type: String },
    childrenArray: [Object],
  },
  { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' }, collection: 'shopping-lists' }
);
```

The problem was in childrenArray, that in the model I had declared this an array of objects. 
Changing this to ChildrenModel solved the problem, cause now these items are saved as mongoose subdocuments and I can operate on then using $ operator.

new Schema looks like this:

```
const Children = new Schema(
  {
    prop1: { type: String, required: true },
    prop2: { type: String, required: true },
    prop3: { type: String },
  },
  { timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdAt' } }
);

const Parent = new Schema(
  {

    description: { type: String },
    products: [ItemSchema],

  },
  { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' }, collection: 'shopping-lists' }
);
```

Now I can easily access subdocuments like this:

```
const { name, isOrdered, author, voterIds, _id, listId } = req.body;

Parent.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: listId, 'children._id': _id },
    {
      $set: {
        'children.$.isOrdered': true
      }
    },
    (err, doc) => {
      console.log(doc);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Are you finding these operations to be efficient?

Comment: Haven't checked the efficiency of these operations bro ;/

Comment: It would probably perform well under load, since that example is keyed on _id.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know We can update the nested document by positional operator that is `$` but as according to the mongodb documentation we cannot update property nested more then 2 levels deep array. In simple you cannot use `$` positional operator two times like `"shoppinglists.$.list.$.products` so its better to change the structure of your db to do it in better way

Comment: i think the right wording is more than 1 level deep. if it is more than 2 levels deep then arr1.$.arr2.$ should be possible so it is only 2 level and not more than 2.